# phpmyadmin shows empty login page after I changed the nameservers to Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, content-security-policy

I have a website on a cloud server running Windows Server 2019 + Apache + PHP + MySQL. I use phpmyadmin to manipulate the database. Everything worked fine for nearly a year till few days ago I made the web service run through Cloudflare. The website itself is still working normally but later I find that phpmyamin has some problems. It shows blank page, which should be a login page, when I use the same link I used before to open it. Then I find in Chrome's developer tool the following message:

> Refused to load the script
> 'https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/7089c43e/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  ". Note that
> 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a
> fallback.

After searching for the cure for hours I still do not get a clue. Could someone please share your remedy? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not just change NS to Cloudflare(CF), you do pass all traffic via CF (observed orange cloud not gray in the CF opt).
Therefore CF injects some scripts into your page:

- [Rocket-Loader.js](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-) (this one causes you issue)
- [Mirage.js](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/219178057) Pro, Business, and Enterprise level domains only
- [BrowserInsights.js](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033929991) to collect some metrics

Therefore you need to [modify your CSP accordingly](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/216537517-What-is-Content-Security-Policy-CSP-and-how-can-I-use-it-with-Cloudflare-) or do traffic bypass CF (make cloud gray and use CF as DNS server only).

Be careful with CloudFlare it brings a lot of surprises (enforced caching for example)

Comment: Thank you very much, @granty! I tried to set CF opt bypassing proxies and then it is accessible now. But I guess it is not a good practice to bypass some of of the records, so  I will look what I can do with CSP. I am not familiar with CSP, hope it is just adding <meta> to the page as from the link you've given.

Comment: You already have CSP, just add https://ajax.cloudflare.com so that script-src looks as: `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ajax.cloudflare.com`. It's enough for Rocket-Loader.js

Comment: I got it! All I have to do to make phpmyadmin accessible is to add `$cfg['CSPAllow']='https://ajax.cloudflare.com';` in config.inc.php. Thanks a lot @granty for helping me realize this and it works fine now.